# How to add table field values and show it in an input when we tick on the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The question is when I tick on the checkbox I want the value of the second span in an input like subtotal, for example, there are two values like 500 in the first row and 200 in the second row , When I tick on first row table checkbox the value should of 500 should be shown in an input with id subtotal but when I also tic on the second checkbox the value should be added in 500 and the total value should be shown in subtotal id like 700, also the tick untick problem is occurring.

I have a table in which some fields are given like service, amount, tax and action are given, The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>table</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Service </th>
        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        <th scope="col">tax</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>Subscription Charges</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>500.00</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>90.00</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>registration fees</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>200.00</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>80.00</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subtotal">
  <input type="text" name="grandtotal" id="grandtotal">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on("change", ".tot_amount", function() {
        var total = 0.00;
        if (this.checked) {
          var subtotal = $(this).closest("tr").find('td').eq(1).find('span').text();
          total += parseFloat($(subtotal).val());
          $('#subtotal').val(total);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is because `subtotal` is a string containing the price selected, therefore converting that to a jQuery selector in `$(subtotal)` is not going to do anything useful.

You also only update the subtotal when a checkbox is checked. Your logic does not subtract the value when an item is unchecked.

To fix both of these issues you can calculate the value of all rows when any checkbox is changed, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".tot_amount", function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.tot_amount:checked').each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) span').text());
    });
    $('#subtotal').val(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Service </th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">tax</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Subscription Charges</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>500.00</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>90.00</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>registration fees</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>200.00</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>80.00</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subtotal">
<input type="text" name="grandtotal" id="grandtotal">
```

Comment: I want only amount value to be added in input , not checkbox value , I mean only second span value like 500 and 200

Comment: I know but that is what I did not want

Comment: What? Your question and comment says you want to get the 'amount' value from the table, which this code does, now you're saying you *don't* want that?

Comment: no due to my bad english you did not understand , Actually I want only table row td second value in an input , for example , I want to add only 500 and 200 value in an input , without tax

Comment: @JayArya did you check the Rory mcCrossan answer, I mean did you run code snippet? It is giving the answer what you have asked...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is working as you expected.

```
var total =0.00;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("change",".tot_amount",function(){
        var subtotal = $(this).closest("tr").find('td').eq(1).find('span').text();
        if (this.checked){ 
            total +=parseFloat(subtotal);
        } else {
            total -=parseFloat(subtotal);
        }
        $('#subtotal').val(total);
    });
});
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan FYI, The link added is a fiddle not any documentation or document